# Separar um DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Gostaria de saber uma forma prática de como separar um DataFrame em vários pelo valor da coluna `state`.

Por exemplo:

```
AC = covid[covid['state'] == 'AC'],   
AL = covid[covid['state'] == 'AL'],   
AM = covid[covid['state'] == 'AM'],   
AP = covid[covid['state'] == 'AP'],
```

Fiz dessa forma, porém se torna muito repetitiva. Tentei de outras maneiras, mas acabei não conseguindo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem que ser feito dessa forma? Qual seu intuito de criar várias variáveis? Abraço!

Comment: Pode ser de outra forma mas oque eu queria era calcular a variação percentual de casos e óbitos de covid para cada estado, pra isso precisava separar os estados calcular a variação e depois juntar tudo de novo.

Comment: pode compartilhar a base de dados?

Comment: https://brasil.io/dataset/covid19/files/

Answer (score 0):

Talvez o *groupby* e o *pct_change* do pandas te ajude

```
df['pct_change_new_confirmed'] = df.groupby('state')['new_confirmed'].pct_change().fillna(0)

df['pct_change_new_deaths'] = df.groupby('state')['new_deaths'].pct_change().fillna(0)
```

- *groupby* serve para fazer o agrupamento
- *pct_change* calcula a variação percentual

Comment: Valeu pela dica me esqueci do groupby abs!